# SERIOUS issue sending a POST request to my server! I'm stuck :(

Tags: java, android, json, post, server

So I've implemented a server and a client (client is an android app),
now I'm trying to send a post HTTP message to my server, 
and my server behaves as if it doesn't get anything!

Here is the funky thing:
I've copy-pasted the values from debug mode in android studio to postman(chrome addon which lets you send different HTTP requests etc),and did that as if I was a bot(didn't add or remove a single char) and EVERYTHING WORKS!! :(

So that's not even debuggable! I'm seriously stuck :(
What am I doing wrong?! Here is the android side code,and values:

```
private static final String POST="POST";


try {

                 URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                 //  open the connection
                 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                 //TODO setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int)
                 //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);     //Should make post request-doesnt work
                 urlConnection.setRequestMethod(POST); //that doesn't work either! :(
                 urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                  out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
                 out.write(json);

                 //urlConnection.connect();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
             }  finally {
                 if (urlConnection != null) {
                     urlConnection.disconnect();
                 }
```

The values that you cannot see from the code above:

builtUri = http://46.121.72.xyz:8080/securitiesFollowServer/users
(I've replaced the three last actual numbers of my IPV4 with xyz for obvious reasons)

json = {"emailPassword":"IM NOT DOR OK","facebookID":"","firstName":"","gcmRegisterToken":"fq-uDL7BMv0:APA91bHH3iAg0UmhgEanUWLQZkRl9plQJR5eBT6Qut-Txz7uQu_wYY9QAc_a5D2EJpvUy3rg9byKWEFgGOMUecwLP0r_2zE0J8Vl7s04quDqMUq9esPU-X6zlvJs51iJYF9ho4dGxxxx","googleID":"","lastContactDate":"1983-01-01 02:00:00.0","lastName":"","picURI":""}

Comment: where is urlConnection.connect(); ?

Comment: It is a commented out, but it is not needed since a write() method is being called (so it automatically connects,or should). You know what? I'll uncomment it right now and let you know

Comment: since it is a buffered output, you need to `out.flush()` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do:

**JSONParser.class**

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JSONParser {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    public StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  HashMap<String, String> params) {

    sbParams = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        try {
            if (i != 0){
                sbParams.append("&");
            }
            sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                    .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (method.equals("POST")) {
        // request method is POST
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            paramsString = sbParams.toString();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("PUT")){
        // request method is GET

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            paramsString = sbParams.toString();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;
}
}
```

and here is how i call

**MainActivity.class**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

public EditText editText;
public EditText editText2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.part_nr);
}






public void Send(View view) {
    new Create_Part().execute();
}

class Create_Part extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Sending part to the database...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        //pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String String_name = editText.getText().toString();
        String Int_Part = editText2.getText().toString();

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Name", String_name);
        params.put("part_nr", Int_Part);

        String URL = String.format("http://10.0.0.2:3000/api/orders/%s/status/%s", Int_Part, String_name);

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "PUT", params);

        try {


            int success = json.getInt("success");
            String message = json.getString("message");
            if(success == 1){

                makeToast(message);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
public void makeToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**NOTE**

> I have made this from some Tutorial 2 Years ago for test and newer used, i forgot name of Author